# javascript: toggle a button's behavior after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer. I want one but could use to Start/Pause/Resume.
[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/xZZ3H/)

Is it something like

```
  toggleButton.click(function(){
    if (){
      Clock.start();
      self.click(function(){
        Clock.pause();
      });
    } else if (){
      Clock.pause();
      self.click(function(){
        Clock.resume();
      })
    } else{
      Clock.resume();
      self.click(function(){
        Clock.pause();
      })
    }
  });
```

It seems working, but I get error in Firebug:

`TypeError: self.click is not a function`

`self.click(function(){`

Comment: What is `self` ?? u want  `$(this)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/rS2aw/)</kbd>

replace `self` with `$(this)`

Read [this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: And, do I code the function is js way? I fear that I'm too verbose.

Comment: @cqcn1991 yes code can be optimized start learning more http://api.jquery.com/ and http://learn.jquery.com/ :)